# href links to old fire version on the server

Tags: file, hyperlink, href

I have a href link which points to a file on the server but the problem is that it sometimes links to an older version of the file. To be able to access the up-to-date version, i need to clear browsing history/cache. I have tried to clear cache with php, but it doesn't help. Any idea why this is happening, and how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a param to link and force the file download.

```
<a href="your-file?v=1">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways based on scenarios

1. Apache Caching directives - If you are the server admin you could use apache's mod_cache to manage caching for specific file(types)
2. Pass the correct HTML header to the browser directing it not to cache it(its its HTML, PHP etc file where you can control the headers of the request)
3. Pass a randomly generated number in the end of the url like - url-to-file?1234. where 1234 is a randomly generated number(you could use timestamp also instead of the random number)